# simple hls server - Streaming from local NAS

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm using FFMPEG to stream to a synology NAS, I cant open the files in VLC over the network. I assume its some sort of CIFS/SMB thing (edit: I think its actually the paths in the .m38u file). I don't really want to setup a nginx server. This is for local use.

Any thoughts on a lightweight solution?

Cheers in advance

Neil

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that my problems stemmed from a bug playing .m3u8 files in vlc versions greater than 3.0.8

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=153329

rolled back, and im now working through a nginx docker container.

Thanks anyway!